# How do I shorten this piece of code for the mean values of each row in Excel?

Tags: excel, pandas, average

Currently this piece of code works, but it seems to repeat itself and so I don't think it's efficient?

First I write out the header names.

Then I save the file and open it as df. Is this necessary?

The df['Average'] part calculates the mean of each row. Without this part Python doesn't plot the "Average" column.

However, without the summary_ave_data part the "Average" values are not input into Excel.

```
sheet1.write(0, 0, "Number")
sheet1.write(0, 1, "Value 1")
sheet1.write(0, 2, "Value 2")
sheet1.write(0, 3, "Average")

book.save('C://Users//user/Desktop/excel_trial1.xls')

df = pd.read_excel("C://Users//user/Desktop/excel_trial1.xls", header=0, 
delim_whitespace=True)

df['Average'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df

summary_ave_data = df.copy()
summary_ave_data['Average'] = summary_ave_data.mean(numeric_only=True, 
axis=1)
print(summary_ave_data)


summary_ave_data.to_excel('C://Users//user/Desktop/excel_trial1.xls')
```

Comment: Are you trying to give name  to  the columns by doing sheet.write?

Comment: Yes! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question; you have data in excel file, then you are giving the name to the columns and you want to find the average of the data along the row and save it in DataFrame.

Comment: Yes, I also want to export the DataFrame to Excel.

Comment: Could you please test the answer in you data?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you already have the data in excel file. You can rename the columns 
once you read the excel by using pandas.

```
df = pd.read_excel("C://Users//user/Desktop/excel_trial1.xls")
df.columns = ['col_name_1', 'col_name_2', 'col_name_3']
```

If any missing values replace them by 0

```
df.fillna(0)
```

or  you can do

```
df.replace(to_replace='Nan', value=0)
```

Then you can save the mean of data in each row

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

**You can run the following test:**

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1], 'b': [3, 4]})
```

I can rename the columns, calculate the mean and add it as a new column by doing this

```
df_test.columns = ['A', 'B']
df_test['mean'] = df_test.mean(axis=1)

df_test
```

Final Output

```
   A  B  mean
0  1  3   2.0
1  1  4   2.5
```

**#you can export the data to excel as following**

```
writer =pd.ExcelWriter('name_df.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
df_test.to_excel(writer,  sheet_name = 'Sheet1' , na_rep = 'Nan')
writer.save()
```

**#see the attached excel screenshot**
[image]

Comment: It says the {} is invalid syntax, then after I changed it to () it says the colon : is invalid syntax

Comment: In which line? please run the test first with the dataframe i provided as an example.

Comment: It doesnot report any error on mine! could you please provide the error?

Comment: In the last part after "options"

Comment: It doesn't write the mean values into Excel

Comment: it works on mine, I am not sure why it doe snot work in yours?